# What does '! image.data' mean in C++?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am a beginner in image processing with OpenCV and Visual Studio. I have a paragraph of code which I don't understand:

```
Mat image;
image = imread(filename, IMREAD_COLOR); // Read the file
if (! image.data )                      // Check for invalid input
{
    cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
    return -1;
}
```

In the third line, what do `!` and `.data` mean? How do they check for invalid input?

Comment: sorry, i am not familiar with the format. please ignore "<br/>" at the end of every line. :)

Comment: It does the same thing as `if (NULL == image.data)`

Comment: It appears you're also a beginner in C++.  This is straightforward usage of the `.` member access operator and the `!` logical negation operator (testing whether the member is a NULL pointer).  Read a good C++ book.  We have [a list of good ones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: And the same thing as any sort of check of a value for null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cv::Mat::data` is a pointer to the data buffer held internally by a `cv::Mat` object. If it evaluates to false, it means no data has been loaded, and the pointer cannot be de-referenced.

It is the equivalent of comparing `image.data` against `NULL`, `0`, or `nullptr` in C++11.